# Content behind a fixed element when overflow

Tags: css, overflow

as you can see in the codepen below, I have a small layout including a fixed header and a fixed sidebar. Inside the sidebar I have another div fixed at the bottom of it, so I want to scroll over the sidebar menu but with the sidebar footer fixed at the bottom (so I add the property `overflow: auto;` to the sidebar.

The problem is that when you make the screen smaller, you can scroll over the sidebar and the footer is fixed, but some content remains under the fixed div (and the scrollbar as well).

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Thanks.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qXmxXa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some corrections need to be done.

First, you are suppose to set the overflow for **.sidebar-body** instead of **.sidebar-container**. Because your fixed footer is inside `.sidebar-container` and sibling of `.sidebar-body`.

And you are suppose to calculate height for `.sidebar-body` as you have to set overflow to it.

And and replace below CSS will help,

1. Remove overflow from `.sidebar-container`
2. Add height for your fixed footer so that you can calculate height of sidebar-body `.sidebar-footer{height:35px;}`
3. Add below CSS `.sidebar-body{height: calc(100% - 35px);overflow: auto;}`

Comment: That's working perfectly, thanks a lot for the explanation!!

Answer (score 0):

add padding for your sidebar-container (fixed-footer height)

```
    padding-bottom: 37px;
```

Comment: or     height: calc(100% - 37px);